# Updating Multiple UserID Records that begin with 'N'

Tags: sql

I need to update over 1000 records. These are user LogIns.

If UserName begins with letter N 
In table Users 
Add perfix of lm\ to existing records

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative option that doesn't use CONCAT:

```
UPDATE 
    Users
SET
    UserName = 'lm\' + UserName 
WHERE
    UserName LIKE 'N%';
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this but for multiple IDs and not ALL Ns? Like give a list of all N IDs that need to be updated?

Comment: You could add an additional where clause for the UserID; 

ie.
UPDATE 
    Users
SET
    UserName = 'lm\' + UserName 
WHERE
    UserName LIKE 'N%' 
AND
    UserID IN (1,2,3,4,5);

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Users SET UserName = CONCAT( 'lm\', UserName ) WHERE UserName LIKE 'N%' AND UserHasNotDemonstratedAnyAttemptAtSolvingTheProblemThemselves = 1
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @NensiDupuy Which DBMS are you using? MySQL 5.0 (and later) and SQL Server 2012 (and later) both support the `CONCAT` function.